# Variable value extract from array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
Array (

[first_value] => 5555

[second_value] => 22222
[third_value] => 3333333
[some_name] => 123456
[fourth_value] => 44444

)
```

My question is how to get only value '123456' from this?

For example `echo $something;` will return me this:

123456

How?

Thanks for help!

Comment: PHP basic documentation on arrays: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(
    'first_value' => 5555,
    'second_value' => 6666
);

$something = $arr['second_value'];

echo $something;  // 6666
```

Comment: Thanks Jaxo I will try it, best regards! UPDATE: there is a small problem because there is not "$arr =" it start exactly as I posted above with "Array (" so it not works. I still need help with this... many thanks!

Comment: That's not possible, you can't create arrays with that syntax. That syntax is only used when printing arrays with `print_r()`.

Comment: Jaxo: There is a small problem because there is not "$arr =" it start exactly as I posted above with "Array (" so it not works. I still need help with this... many thanks!

Comment: You already said that, so I'll repeat: that's not a valid PHP program with that notation.

Comment: Barmar: yes, it is that, correctly it is from print_r(), but how I can get from that print_r() result  "123456" (in my scripting above) or just result "123456" without using print_r().

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get print_r() to only print a particular value out of your array. It doesn't do that. If you do print_r($your_array) it prints your entire array. Same with var_dump(). The answer above will print the value you're trying to get. Alternately, you could simply do echo $arr['some_name'] directly and it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The result I got when I use print_r() is exactly what I already posted above. How to get simple '123456' from that? I can't use $something = $arr['second_value']; because I try it and it and <?php echo $something; ?> return me nothing. Again: there is not any '$arr =' - instead of that my result start with 'Array ('

Comment: The result would only start with 'Array (' if you were using print_r(). Can you post the actual code you're working on? You've only posted output so far. We need to see what you're actually trying to do before we can help you further.

Comment: okay I got it - many thanks all for help: the problem is because it not start with $arr but only with $ar and after tried to get echo using '$ar' it working perfectly! Many thanks again! Best regards!